# snap.js set.animate(array) wont work as desired

Tags: snap.svg

I try to animate a Snap.js Set (snap 0.5.1) with Set.animate(). In the Manual I can read 
http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Set.animate this:

```
// animate first element to radius 10, but second to radius 20 and in different time
set.animate([{r: 10}, 500, mina.easein], [{r: 20}, 1500, mina.easein]);
```

In the manual I can read, that I can pass an array of animations as the first argument like

```
Set.animate(arr)
```

but this doesn't work.

If I try

```
set.animate([{r: 10}, 500, mina.easein], [{r: 20}, 1500, mina.easein]);
```

this woks well. But if I try

```
var arr = [[{r: 10}, 500, mina.easein], [{r: 20}, 1500, mina.easein]];
set.animate(arr);
```

will result in this Error

```
InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character snap.svg.js:1000
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: Can you try something like set.animate.apply( null, arr ) ? As apply method takes an array.

Comment: sorry, no! set.animate.apply( null, arr ) results in an error: TypeError: this.forEach is not a function

Comment: Hmm does look a bit buggy unless I misunderstand it. If it's any use, I wrote a basic animator plugin for Snap a while back, that allows synced and sequenced animations at https://jsfiddle.net/bf238wf8/62/ that could be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! - I will take a closer look to your fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bug, it's the fact you are passing an array of arrays, instead of an array into the parameters, which is where I was leading before in the comments.

So I think this may work (as it will unfold the arrays into the parameter list)...

```
set.animate.apply( set, arr );
```

eg http://jsfiddle.net/3nmL6tz1/